# Filter name to indicate the messages the user is CCed on: I'm CCed on? CCed me?

Tags: filter, ux-writing

We are developing an email system where the user can filter and sort all email messages they receive.
When it comes to naming filters, I need your suggestions for those that include the user as a principal recipient and as a CC recipient, respectively.

We are considering...

1. To: Addressed to me
2. CC: I'm CCed on / CCed me

Because of relationships with other UX names, we can't change 1). Given this situation, which of the two options for 2) is the better one?
Or, is there any better suggestion?

Comment: "2. CC: I'm in CC" would make sense to me. However, I think this question is better suited for https://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a question of English language usage and should be moved to https://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @greenforest I think you're on point that it's related to English language. However, I think it's about user experience. I can see clear differences in language tone, voice, and length. Also, in the context of Universal UX this is a very good question. For example, in Spanish CC is also CC, although the initials have a different meaning. Doing a literal translation, one option is really ambiguous (what does "CCed On" mean?). The other is very clear

Comment: Nomenclature in the context of UX is on topic. Voted to keep open.

Comment: Also voting to keep open: the wrong word in the wrong place can kill an interface.

Answer (score 1):

"CCed to me" sounds better English.  It's also consistent with the first option.

Comment: I agree. Also, as a non-native English speaker I think it's more intuitive, probably because it's simpler and shorter